# Word Online add in only loads sometimes

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I have made an add in for word online. When I sideload the manifest file in Word online all works fine.

When i am deploying the manifest file to the account user's from the office online portal, add in only loads some times. When it (some times) loads all works.

When the add in not loads- I can some time force it to load by refresh multiply times, run incognito mode or delete all browser data and login again

It is the same behavior when using IE, Egede or Chrome

Any idea for resolving that behavior

Comment: Two links were posted in the incorrect place, so were deleted. But since they may help you, here they are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest

Comment: If you're doing all of these operations on the same machine, just make sure the user is logged in with a single account.